# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined at Timeout.onDownload

Tags: javascript, node.js

i try to download a file in an interval of 24hours. To test the program, i need to run my function for download the program. But, each time im running my function i have this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checksum') at Timeout.onDownload

here is the function :

```
require('isomorphic-fetch')
const converterCsvToJson = require("csvtojson");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const PATH_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD = path.join(__dirname, "./files");
 
if(!fs.existsSync(PATH_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(PATH_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD);
}
 
const TIME_DOWNLOAD_INTERVAL = ((1_000 * 60) * 60) * 24; // 24 hours
const downloadRid = setInterval(onDownload, TIME_DOWNLOAD_INTERVAL);
 
async function onDownload() {
 
    const response = await fetch('https://www.data.gouv.fr/api/2/datasets/6010206e7aa742eb447930f7/resources/?page=1&type=main&page_size=1', {
        method: "GET"
    });
 
    const data = response.json();
    const lastItem = data[0];
 
    const integrity = lastItem.checksum.value;
    const filenames = fs.readdirSync(PATH_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD, {encoding: "utf-8"});
 
    const exists = filenames.find(filename => (
        filename.indexOf(integrity) !== -1
    ));
 
    if(exists) {
        const {published} = lastItem;
        console.log(`opération annulé, aucun fichier à été publié depuis le: ${published}`);
 
    } else {
        const urlCsvFile = lastItem.url;
        const response = await fetch(urlCsvFile, {method: "GET"});
        const csvContent = await response.text();
 
        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.join(PATH_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD, (integrity + ".csv")),
            csvContent,
            {encoding: "utf-8"}
        ); 

        const json = await converterCsvToJson().fromString(csvContent);
        console.log(json);
 
    }
}

onDownload();
```

thanks for your help,
have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Looking manually at the response from the endpoint you're looking at: https://www.data.gouv.fr/api/2/datasets/6010206e7aa742eb447930f7/resources/?page=1&type=main&page_size=1 - it's clear that this is a JSON *object* (as is standard for most APIs), rather than an array as you're expecting when you index with `const lastItem = data[0];`.

The array of data that you seem to want - it includes objects with a `checksum` property - is held in the `data` property of the JSON object.

So you just need to replace this:

```
const lastItem = data[0];
```

with

```
const lastItem = data.data[0];
```

Comment: thanx its effectively solve this error but now i have the same error with '0' (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')). I dont have have any ideas of why it does so if you could enlighten me pls

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that if your other code is exactly as shown in the question, including the API endpoint. If in doubt try `console.log(data)` and explore the object yourself.